# Faster TimerOne with Teensy 4.0 (600MHz)

Tags: interrupt, timers, teensy

I have a teensy 4.0 which runs at 600MHz, and is double superscaler (i.e. can execute two instructions per clock cycle, sometimes). I need an interrupt to happen faster than every microsecond. I've calculated that it's possible for the processor to run the my code at that speed with some reasonable overhead. **Can TimerOne (or similar) be set to produce an interrupt more than once per microsecond?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about the library `TimerOne` or about the timer itself?

Comment: @chrisl well I've been using the TimerOne library but if the only way to get a faster interrupt is to not use that library then that's OK with me.

Comment: https://forum.pjrc.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TeensyTimerTool](https://github.com/luni64/TeensyTimerTool) for this. It provides a generic interface to the hardware timers (TMR, GPT, PIT) and 20 software timers. Since the coupling of the timer peripherals to the ARM core is rather inefficient, the software timers might be a better fit for sub micro second interrupts. 
If you prefer the hardware timers I suggest to use a GPT timer (also supported by the lib). You can configure it to use a 150MHz clock instead of the standard 24MHz clock. So something like 2MHz interrupt rate should be feasible.

Documentation can be found here: https://github.com/luni64/TeensyTimerTool/wiki

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the Teensy 3.5.
I found that using the "Periodic Interrupt Timer (PIT)" let me generate interrupt every 300 ns.
I imagine that with a Teensy 4.0, it must be possible to generate an interrupt every 100 ns.
Here is the code which works for me on my Teensy 3.5,
with comments in french and some references in the comments.
I test the signal on an oscilloscope.

```cpp
// ex00305_Timer_pit0_isr_rapide.ino
/*

FONCTIONNE TRES BIEN

Le signal n'est pas très stable, mais acceptable.
J'imagine que d'autres routines d'interruption perturbe la précision, comme la routine millis()

L'instruction suivante améliore la stabilité. visiblement.
NVIC_SET_PRIORITY(IRQ_PIT_CH0, 0);

Le but est de tester l'utilisation du Timer1 .c.f
/home/bg/Arduino/Teensy/Teensy_3_5_manual_K64P144M120SF5RM.pdf
Page 1083, Chapter 41 : "Periodic Interrupt Timer (PIT)"

Pour la gestion des timers PIT, c.f.
====================================
https://github.com/loglow/PITimer/blob/master/PITimer.cpp

********************************************************************************** */

#define PINOUT1 34
#define LEDRED  24
#define LEDYELLOW  25
#define LEDGREEN  26

volatile byte bEtat = 0;

void setup() {
    //============
    pinMode(PINOUT1, OUTPUT);
    digitalWriteFast(PINOUT1, HIGH);

    pinMode(33, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(34, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(LEDRED, OUTPUT);  digitalWriteFast(LEDRED, LOW);
    pinMode(LEDYELLOW, OUTPUT);  digitalWriteFast(LEDYELLOW, LOW);
    pinMode(LEDGREEN, OUTPUT);  digitalWriteFast(LEDGREEN, LOW);

    //if (SIM_SCGC6_PIT == 0b100000000000000000000000) digitalWriteFast(LEDYELLOW, HIGH);
    SIM_SCGC6 |= SIM_SCGC6_PIT; // C.f. page 317.  PIT Clock Gate Control   SIM_SCGC6_PIT == 0b100000000000000000000000

    // C.f. : /home/bg/.arduino15/packages/teensy/hardware/avr/1.58.1/cores/teensy3/kinetis.h
    // #define NVIC_ENABLE_IRQ(n) (*((volatile uint32_t *)0xE000E100 + ((n) >> 5)) = (1 << ((n) & 31)))
    // enable IRQ Interrupt
    NVIC_SET_PRIORITY(IRQ_PIT_CH0, 0); // Haute priorité, pour ne pas être perturbé par d'autres interrupt. Amélioration visible !
    NVIC_ENABLE_IRQ(IRQ_PIT_CH0);
    PIT_TCTRL0 = 3; // 0b011;  // enable Timer 0 interrupts ; start Timer 0   IRQ_PIT_CH0 == 48  Dans #elif defined(__MK64FX512__)
    //if (IRQ_PIT_CH0 == 48) digitalWriteFast(LEDGREEN,  HIGH);

    // Efface le flag du timer, pour permettre d'autres interruptions, nécessaire au départ
    PIT_TFLG0 = 1;

    // L'ordre des instruction a de l'importance !
    //""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
    PIT_MCR = 0;  // turn on PIT
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 600-1;  // == 10 micro secondes setup timer 0 for xxx cycles Fréqu = 60 MHz  dt = 16.666 ns
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 120-1;  // == 2 micros second
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 60-1;   // == 1 micros second
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 30-1;   // == 500 ns
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 24-1;   // == 400 ns
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 21-1;   // == 350 ns
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 20-1;   // == 333 ns
    //PIT_LDVAL0 = 18-1;   // == 300 ns
    PIT_LDVAL0 = 120-1;
} // setup

void loop() {
    //===========
} // loop

void pit0_isr() {  // C.f. mk20dx128.c
    //===============
    // J'espère pouvoir gérer un temps

    // Efface le flag du timer, pour permettre d'autres interruptions
    // Doit être mis en début de routine !!!
    PIT_TFLG0 = 1;

    if (bEtat) {
        digitalWriteFast(PINOUT1, HIGH);
        //digitalWriteFast(LEDRED,  HIGH);
        bEtat = 0;
    }
    else {
        bEtat = 1;
        digitalWriteFast(PINOUT1, LOW);
        //digitalWriteFast(LEDRED,  LOW);
    }

} // pit0_isr
```